# Compare a variable to an specific string array object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison

I'm new to javascript and trying to do a simple guessing color game, this is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Guessing Color Game</title>
</head>
<body onload="do_game()">
<script>

    var target;
    var colors;
    var finished = false;
    var guess_input;
    var guesses = 0;


    var random_number = Math.random() * 11;
    var random_number_index = Math.floor(random_number);

    colors = ["Aqua", "Black", "Blue", "Brown", "Cyan", "Grey", "Green", "Orange", "Red", "White", "Yellow"];
    target = colors[random_number_index];

    function do_game() {

        alert("Hello mate, wanna play a game???");
        alert("You gotta guess a color, alright???");
        alert("Available colors are: \n\n0. Aqua \n1. Black \n2. Blue \n3. Brown \n4. Cyan \n5. Grey \n6. Green \n7. Orange" +
            " \n8. Red \n9. White \n10. Yellow");
        alert("Random color to guess is " + target + ", which is index " + random_number_index + " in the array");

        while (!finished) {
            guess_input = prompt("Write the name of your chosen color please:").toLowerCase();
            guesses++;
            finished = check_guess();
        }
    }

    function check_guess() {
        if (target == guess_input)
            return true;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is with the check_guess() function: I'm having an infinite loop due to target is not being compared with guess_input. Why is this so?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: That was the issue Sandeep, thank you for the explanation, now is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking `target` color with lowercased `guess_input`.

Instead, apply `.toLowerCase()` to both `target` and `guess_input` or neither.

You need to check `.toLowerCase()` of `target` color with that of `guess_input`.

So the only change you need to do is below:

`colors[random_number_index].toLowerCase();`

```js
  var target;
  var colors;
  var finished = false;
  var guess_input;
  var guesses = 0;


  var random_number = Math.random() * 11;
  var random_number_index = Math.floor(random_number);

  colors = ["Aqua", "Black", "Blue", "Brown", "Cyan", "Grey", "Green", "Orange", "Red", "White", "Yellow"];
  target = colors[random_number_index].toLowerCase();

  function do_game() {

    alert("Hello mate, wanna play a game???");
    alert("You gotta guess a color, alright???");
    alert("Available colors are: \n\n0. Aqua \n1. Black \n2. Blue \n3. Brown \n4. Cyan \n5. Grey \n6. Green \n7. Orange" +
      " \n8. Red \n9. White \n10. Yellow");
    alert("Random color to guess is " + target + ", which is index " + random_number_index + " in the array");

    while (!finished) {
      guess_input = prompt("Write the name of your chosen color please:").toLowerCase();
      guesses++;
      finished = check_guess();
    }
  }

  function check_guess() {
    console.log(target, guess_input)
    if (target == guess_input)
      return true;
  }

  do_game();
```

Comment: That was the issue Sandeep, thank you for the explanation, now is clear.

Comment: @Fabricio: Great!. If the answer helped resolve the issue you then you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function check_guess() {
  if (target === guess_input) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: same looping result